# Consultar tabela por data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Galera, tenho uma tabela que os dados são gravados da seguinte maneira:

```
ID CANAL VALOR DATA
25 10    50    2016-10-14 14:10:05
26 11    12    2016-10-14 14:10:06
27 10    51    2016-10-14 15:10:10
```

Ambos registros são gravados de hora em hora, logo preciso consultá-los e mostrar eles um à um por canal.

Estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
$contador = 0;
while($contador <= 24){

  if($contador == 0){
    $horario[$contador] = '00:00';
  } else {
    $horario[$contador] = '0'.$contador.':00';
  }

  $data = "2016-10-14";

  $query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM valores_d WHERE data_hora BETWEEN ('2016-13 12:00:00') AND ('2016-10-15 13:00:00') order by id desc limit 1");
  $resultado = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  $arr[$contador] = $resultado['valor'];

  $contador++;

}
```

Comment: qual seria a dúvida?

Comment: Preciso trazer os registros da seguinte forma:
Valor: 30
Hora: 15:10:10

Valor: 35
Hora: 16:10:10

Comment: especifique, você quer retornar os registros de acordo com a data, tipo, os registros mais novos primeiros, ou os mais antigos, ou os primeiros são os que te mais valor?

Comment: Preciso dos últimos 24 registros das horas,
por exemplo, registro da hora 00:00, 01:00 até 23:00

Comment: A questão parece fácil, mas ficou confuso o que realmente deseja. Acredito que tudo isso possa ser resolvido usando somente SQL.

Comment: porque não faz a colunda DATA e a HORA para especificar a data na hpra da pesquisa?